# TikZ: Making a custom length independent from scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I've defined a custom length for drawing dots in `tikzpicture`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\point}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw (1,1) circle[radius=\point];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But sometimes in more complex drawings, I would scale the whole picture down with a global (optional) `scale=0.7` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\point}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7] % Scaled!
    \filldraw (1,1) circle[radius=\point];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is, that since the length is not predefined like `\pgflinewidth`, the radius of the point will also scale down. Is there a way to make it independet from scaling like `\pgflinewidth`?

**Edit**: To clarify my goal: I want to leave the radius of the circle under scaling untouched, but the midpoint should obviously scale. The MWE in that sense isn't optimal, since the circle sits at the origin (changed it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You could locally reset the transformation matrix with option `reset cm` (or `shift only` if you want to retain shifting part):</s>

Correction: `reset cm` resets even the center of circle to the origin, which is wrong. Applying `shift only` to `circle[...]` seems to work.

Using `pic` works for more general drawings. `pic`s, like `node`s, only apply the shifting part by default.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\point}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
Before: \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7] % Scaled!
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \filldraw (0,0) circle[radius=\point]
              (1,1) circle[radius=\point];
\end{tikzpicture}

Using \verb|circle[shift only ...]|: \\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7] % Scaled!
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \filldraw (0,0) circle[shift only, radius=\point]
              (1,1) circle[shift only, radius=\point];
\end{tikzpicture}

Using \verb|pic|: \\
\tikzset{
  dot/.pic={
    \filldraw circle[radius=\point];
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7] % Scaled!
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \draw (0,0) pic {dot}
          (1,1) pic {dot};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The ultimate solution is to extend `tikz`, `pgf`, and perhaps the underlying `pgfmath` so that they all recognize some sort of absolute dimension and follow some absoluteness composition rules.

Comment: Or `\pgftransformresetnontranslations ` and use `\begin{scope}[ shift = { (1, 2) } ]` outside the `\drawfill` to move your circle.

Comment: I've read in the manual (p. 379): *This will destroy not only the transformations applied in the current scope, but also all transformations inherited from surrounding scopes.* Does that mean, that the scaling afterwards is reset too?

Comment: @Gargantuar Each path command (here `\filldraw`) starts a new group, so the effect of `\filldraw[reset cm]` is local.

Comment: @Symbol1 I've added `shift only` to answer, which seems to be equivalent to what you suggest, does it?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ After trying it out, the problem is that this only works at the origin (which I forgot to mention). Using `reset cm` not only resets scaling of the radius, but also scaling of the coordinates, which I want to retain. P.S.: `shift only` also doesn't help.

Comment: @Gargantuar Answer updated. Not the best.

Comment: @G `shift only` should help (I tested). If you have any counterexample please update. We can debug together.

Comment: @Symbol1 Yeah, it works indeed, sry about that. I've added `shift only` as an optional parameter to `\filldraw`, not `circle`. But tbh, I think the `pic` solution is the prettiest.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to divide your radius by your scale:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\point}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw circle[radius=\point];
\end{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\scl}{0.7}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scl] % Scaled!
    \filldraw circle[radius=\point/\scl];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also already had the idea, but then I have to manually multiply by the scale, which could change across `tikzpicture`s.